# Vuejs v-for without JSON object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, v-for

I simply want to loop the numbers from 0 to 19 using a v-for attribute.
I already tried this:
`<div v-for="number in [...Array(6).keys()]" v-bind:key="number">`
And this:
`<div v-for="let i = 0; i < 20; i++" v-bind:key="i">`
Of course I could just use an array with all numbers, but I think there is a better way to do this.

Comment: just do `v-for="i in 20"`

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think it would be as easy as that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop through a fixed  `n` number  like :

```
 <div v-for="i in 20" v-bind:key="i">
```

Comment: That loop starts at 1 instead of 0